# Number Power , multiple of 3

Tags: math, logic, aptitude

We have a Number N  and Cost C,(range N<10^18 ,C<100)
Now we have to spend maximum of C rupees to convert the number into another.

The rules of conversion of a number to another are as follows:

1)A number can be converted into other number with same number of digits and no leading zeros.
2)The cost of converting a number into other is the sum of absolute difference of corresponding digits. For example, Cost to convert 235 to 331 is 5 (since the absolute difference in corresponding digits is |3−2|+|3−3|+|1−5| , which is |1|+0+|−4|=5.
Now we need to find how many numbers that are multiple of 3, which can be made within the maximum budget(C rupees).

My approach:
i tried first to use divisibility rule of 3 and find sum of digits of N
now if cost was just sum of difference of digits then we could simply do is make the sum a multiple of 3
like 2+3+5 = 10 cost is 2
we can make it 12 which can be achieved by increasing any number 2 , 3 or 5 by 2
435,255, 237 is this correct?
also how to go about solving it in this case when c is absolute sum

Comment: This looks like homework.

Excerpt from StackOverflow Help Center: 

`3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`

Comment: but it is not. i found this problem on the web and was keen to know hoe to solve it

Comment: Still. You haven't shown any signs of yourself trying to attack the problem.

Comment: @akrasuski1  i wasn't aware about it .why did you down vote the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let *cost(a,b)* denote the cost of transforming *a* into *b* and define

```
 N(a,c) = # { b | cost(a,b) = c }
```

i.e., *N(a,c)* is the number of numbers whose cost from *a* is exactly *c*.

Let's futher suppose _a_is divisible by 3. Then the number we are interested in is:

```
 answer = N(a,0) + N(a,3) + N(a,6) + N(a,9) + ... + N(a,99)
```

If *a* was 1 mod 3 we would want the sum *N(a,2) + N(a,5) + ... + N(a,98)*.

To compute *N(a,c)*, for each digit *d* in *a*, construct a polynomial *P(d)* where
the coefficient of *x^k* is the number of digits in [0..9] which are exactly *k*
away from *d*. These coefficients will always be 0, 1 or 2.

For example, for *a* = 3496 the polynomials are:

```
  d   1  x  x^2 x^3 x^4 x^5 x^6 x^7 x^8 x^9
 -- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---   
  3   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
  4   1   2   2   2   2   1   0   0   0   0
  9   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  6   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

N.B.: The coefficient of *x^3* for the digit 3
is 1 and not 2 because leading zeros are not allowed.

Now multiply the polynomials together and *N(a,c)* is coefficient of *x^c*
in the resulting product.